# How to run deployable code in visual studio that exist in another website subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I have asp.net web form website and folder name is `Mywebsite` and under that folder I have NC folder with nopcommerce Deployable code. I am already setup on iis and iis there is option of Convert to application and this works on iis. Like when i put url like `mywebsite.com` that opens my `aspx` website and when put URL like `mywebsite.com/NC` then opens the nopcommerce site.

But how to run NC(Deployable Code that exist in sub-folder of `aspx` website)in visual studio.

like when I am put URL `localhost:8055` then its opening my `aspx` site but when I put URL of `localhost:8055/NC.`

I have create virtual directory of NC Folder but its not working and give me error of

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

I have also change the Directory browsing to true in `applicationhost.config` file but its opening up NC directory.

How to open a NC(deployable code) that exist in aspx website in visual studio at same port?

[Webisite Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Umf.png)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPjg8.png)

Comment: I don't quite get it....You want to run two website on the same domain and the same URL, but not at the same time?

Comment: Run them on different ports? eg. localhost:40001 and localhost:40002

Comment: i have asp.net web form website folder name is My website and under that folder i have NC folder with nopcommerce mvc code. I am already setup on iis and like when i put url like mywebsite.com that opens my aspx website and when put url like mywebsite.com/NC then opens the nopcommerce site it is working on iis but how to run in visual studio. like when i am put url localhost:8055 then its opening my aspx site but when i put url of ocalhost:8055/NC then its not opening gives error.